# Equivalent to weighted random sample?

Tags: sampling, weighted-sampling

Let's say that you have a list of numbers and a weight for each number e.g.

X = [(1, 2342), (2, 55), (3...]

In the above example, 2342 and 55 are weights.

Is weighted random sampling N items from X equal to randomly splitting X into N equal partitions and weighted randomly sampling 1 item from each part?

Comment: What statistic are you calculating?

Comment: I want to split X as a performance optimization - the input is quite large. I'm hoping to split X, sample each split, and then combine the samples from each split into a final sample.

I'm calculating on the total size N sample something similar to the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.

Here is a simpler example that demonstrates the problem.

Suppose you we have an array $X = [1,2,3,4]$, and want to randomly select two values, without replacement, from that array. There are six possible outcomes: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), and (3,4) and, if each data point is equally weighted, they should all be equally likely and chosen with probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

However, suppose we try your scheme and divide the array into $X_1 = [1,2]$ and $X_2 = [3,4]$, then sample one value from $X_1$ and another from $X_2$. There are now only four possible outcomes: (1,3), (1,4), (2, 3), and (2, 4); this approach cannot generate the remaining two outcomes of (1,2) and (3,4). In other words, it assigns zero probability to these pairs and 0.25 to each of the remaining ones.

The same situation holds with weighted values. You can turn the weighted selection problem into an unweighted one by "expanding" the vector such that it contains 2342 copies of 1, 55 copies of 2, and so on.

---

Edit: From your comment, it sounds like you *want* to sample from the entire array, but somehow cannot (perhaps it's too large). Fortunately, there is a clever algorithm for doing this: [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

As a simple example, suppose you want to select one item at random from a list of large (or even unknown) size.

- You start by keeping the first item.
- When the second item arrives, you randomly decide to keep the old "saved" item (with probability 0.5) or replace it with the new one (with probability 0.5 also).
- For the third item, we keep the saved item (so either the first or second) with probability 2/3, or save the new item with probability 1/3.
- In general, the $k$th new item is saved with probability 1/k, and ignored (in favor of the previously saved one) with probability $1-\frac{1}{k}$.

At every time step, the saved element has been uniformly sampled from the $k$ elements that you've already seen, all while using a small, constant amount of memory (the total number of elements, plus the saved item).

This is a really basic version of the algorithm. Fairly simple extensions can allow you to sample multiple, weighted items, from a larger stream.

Comment: This makes sense! Would the above still be the case if we randomly split X into 2 equal partitions?

Comment: Nope, same problem--the split will make at least one pair impossible. However, I think I see where you're going with this and have a solution (see edit).

Comment: I've tried the distributed version of reservoir sampling that's suppose to be *correct* for my problem but it just doesn't scale. My N is a few trillion and my sample size is 1 million and I'm running across thousands of machines :(

Comment: Hmmm...It's possible to do unweighted reservoir sampling in linear time, but I think the standard "Algoirthm A" version for weighted samples takes O(N * log(sample_size)) time, which is much much worse. There's a modified version ('exponential jumps') that needs fewer random numbers, which may help.

Alternately, could you relax the problem a bit and ignore the weights? Or consider sampling less, or with replacement instead (which would let you run many samplers in parallel)